# How to change the "Parent Content Type"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, content-type, visual-studio

I have requirement to create multiple content types to a single website in Sharepoint 2013, I have did it using the template files, but the problem in for all newly created content types the parent Content Type is Document, Please suggest me a way how to change the "Parent Content Type" programatically using C#

Thanks in advance
K Harsha

Answer (score 7):

TLDR: **You have to re-create the content types using the correct parent content type!**

You cannot change the parent content type of a content type:

- The [**Parent** property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.parent.aspx) is read-only.
- The content type ID is prefixed with the parent content type's ID. See explanation below copied from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543822(v=office.14).aspx). This is for SP 2010 but it works the same for SP 2013 and later versions of SharePoint, including SP Online.

> Content type IDs uniquely identify the content type and are designed
>   to be recursive. The content type ID encapsulates that content type's
>   lineage, or the line of parent content types from which the content
>   type inherits. Each content type ID contains the ID of the parent
>   content type, which in turn contains the ID of that content type's
>   parent, and so on, ultimately back to and including the System content
>   type ID. SharePoint Foundation uses this information to determine the
>   relationship between content types and for push-down operations.
>
> You can construct a valid content type ID using one of two
>   conventions:
>
> - Parent content type ID + two hexadecimal values (the two hexadecimal
>     values cannot be "00")
> - Parent content type ID + "00" + hexadecimal GUID

Comment: Thank u Mihail Popa, I wil try with that solution and i wil let u know